# Wireless multi-function printer setup problem on Feren OS

Tags: distributions, printer, scanner

Trying out Feren OS 2023.04.  It does not see my wireless printer.  I was able to manually configure it & successfully print, but then it would not recognize the scanner function of the printer. That is, when I opened the scanner app, the app said no scanner was found. I have tried many Linux operating systems the last several years & cannot recall another os that did not immediately find my printer/scanner & automatically have it ready for printing & scanning.  For an os that claims to be for the average user, I find this frustrating.

Comment: from browsing the Feren OS website, this seems to be a niche distro based rather closely on Ubuntu with KDE (so, practically a Kubuntu with attitude, and a preference for scones instead of donuts?). Whether or not there's a driver for your networked scanner: impossible to tell without knowing your scanner model!

Comment: Is Avahi running?

Comment: Ok thanks.  Just seems that it should "just work" like 99.9% of the other ubuntu based distros I have tried.  I do not know what Avahi is, but again to me it should already be running.  I guess I am a Linux "Karen" (or actually, Ken!).  Not going to install it of course.  Thanks for your responses.

Comment: please be more precise: commands used, outputs received, hardware involved